# CDO CreateMHTMLBody locks the file in JScript

Tags: vbscript, jscript

I'm making a JScript script that sends e-mail messages in HTML format via CDO. I have a message template in .html file, and I put some unique data into each message being sent. So, I create a copy of the original .html file for each message.

The problem is that I cannot detele this temporary file from within script after sending the message. I've checked with ProcessExplorer, which process locks the file, and it is cscript.exe/wscript.exe (wichever is being used to run the script).

Here is the example (simplified) code:

```
//-------------------------------------------
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var BodyFileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(3));
var BodyExtensionName = fso.GetExtensionName(BodyFileName)
var BodyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(BodyFileName, 1);
var Body = BodyFile.ReadAll();
BodyFile.Close();
//-------------------------------------------
// Replace something in Body here
//-------------------------------------------
BodyFileName = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(BodyFileName), fso.GetTempName() + "." + BodyExtensionName);
var TmpBodyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(BodyFileName, 2, true);
TmpBodyFile.Write(Body);
TmpBodyFile.Close();
// Here ProcessExplorer shows that the file is closed
//-------------------------------------------
var objEmail = new ActiveXObject("CDO.Message");  
objEmail.From = WScript.Arguments(0);
objEmail.To = WScript.Arguments(1);  
objEmail.Subject = WScript.Arguments(2);  
objEmail.CreateMHTMLBody("file:///" + BodyFileName.replace("\\","/"));
// Here the file is open again
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2;  
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "192.168.0.1";
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25;  
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update();  
objEmail.Send();
objEmail = null;
//-------------------------------------------
// The following loop becomes endless
for (;;) {
  try {
    fso.DeleteFile(BodyFileName, true);
  } catch(e) {
    WScript.Sleep(100);
    continue;
  } finally {
  }
  break;
}
//-------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try programmatically killing the mail prcess and then deleting the file(Unless you need the mail program running after you send the mail)

Do you have IIS SMTP service installed, might be worth trying

CreateObject("cdonts.NewMail")

or

CreateObject("outlook.application")

But you might have to kill the related process in a similar situation.